# Why does Theta in an OU process relate to a mispricing of a pair's spread

Tags: algorithmic-trading, pairs-trading, ornstein-uhlenbeck

I am reading this article from Alex Lipton and Marcos Lopez de Prado: [A closed-form solution for optimal mean-reverting trading strategies (2020)](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2003.10502.pdf) which talks about finding optimal profit taking and stop loss limits when trading a mean reverting spread. He does so by modeling the spread as an OU process.

In section 7, he says the following: "when the original mispricing is strong (θ = 1) it is not optimal to stop the trade early. When the mispricing is weaker (θ = 0.5) or there is no mispricing in the first place (θ = 0) it is not optimal to stop losses"

My question is why does the theta (long term equilibrium) of an OU process relate to (original) mispricing? Wouldn't the mispricing be strong if the current value of the spread is far from theta? (independent of the actual value of theta)? (|x-theta| >> 0)

I don't understand OU processes enough but the way I'm reading this passage, it seems that he's saying that the trading rules depend on whether the OU process is centered at 0 or shifter up one unit, which doesn't make sense.

Comment: IIUC the pricing error is random, but not necessarily centered at 0. There could be a consistent long term mispricing, which is represented by $\theta$. If $\theta >>0$ then the random error seldom goes negative, so  it behooves you to get out of the trade when the mispricing is small enough, but still there. That my interpretation, TBH I am not sure how you would set $\theta$ in practice, I usually assume $\theta=0$ (as I think the literature usually does).

Comment: I think the authors are calling $\theta$ a mispricing term, not that the current rice or the asset is mispriced. In other words, it's not saying anything about the _true_ current value of the asset currently being higher or lower, rather; the authors are saying if $\theta$ is large, it is not optimal to stop the trade early.